# Ошибка "Too many initializer values" при присвоении массиву значений

Tags: c++, массивы, инициализация

Код C++

```
unsigned char *a;
a = (unsigned char *)malloc(5);
a[5] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05};
```

выдаёт ошибку `too many initializer values`.

Исправляю, получая следующий код:

```
unsigned char *a;
a = (unsigned char *)malloc(5);
a[0] = 0x01;
a[1] = 0x02;
a[2] = 0x03;
a[3] = 0x04;
a[4] = 0x05;
```

который компилируется без ошибки.

В чём причина?

И какое отличие данного способа от `unsigned char a[5] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05}`?

Comment: Если вы знакомы с элементарным синтаксисом С и С++, то вы должны понимать, что `a[5]` - это доступ к одному-единственному элементу массива `a` с индексом `5`. Почему вы ожидали, что доступ к одному-единственному `a[5]` вам как-то запишет данные в *весь* массив?

Comment: @Harry рука дрогнула [при] установке меток?

Comment: @älёxölüt Видимо, да...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В том, что такого "синтаксического сахара" для присваивания не придумывали и не реализовывали - этот синтаксис только для *инициализации*.

А вы пытаетесь синтаксис инициализации приспособить под присваивание.

Но это только называется С++, потому что в С++ вы бы использовали не `malloc`, а `vector`:

```
vector<unsigned char> a;
a = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05};
```

И вот с ним такой фокус [получился бы](https://ideone.com/cKPDJZ).

Answer (score 5):

В языке С++, начиная с С++11 синтаксис инициализации прекрасно применим в присваивании. Язык будет использовать `{}`-инициализатор для создания временного объекта, который и будет являться правой частью оператора присваивания.

Например

```
struct XY { int x, y; char a[3]; };
XY xy = { 1, 2, { 3, 4 } }; // <- Так можно 
xy = { 3, 4, { 5, 6 } };    // <- И так тоже можно
```

Такой фокус однако не пройдет с целым массивом, т.к. массивы в С++ по-прежнему не присваиваемы.

Однако в вашем коде вы даже и не пытаетесь этого сделать. `a[5]` - это единственный элемент массива, типа `char`. (К тому же этот элемент находится за пределами массива. Максимальный индекс в вашем массиве - `4`, а вы пытаетесь обращаться к некоему `a[5]`, которого не существует.) Обратившись к некоему `a[5]`, вы в этот объект типа `char` пытаетесь запихнуть некое `{0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05}`. В один `char` объект невозможно запихнуть 5 значений, о чем вам и говорит компилятор. В один `char` объект можно положить только одно значение. Например

```
a[3] = { 0x02 };
```

В данном случае скобки `{}` не обязательны, но и ошибкой они не являются.

Как уже сказано выше, голые массивы в С++ по прежнему не присваиваемы. Самое близкое к тому, что вы пытались сделать, можно разве что сделать через `memcpy`

```
using A = unsigned char[5];
std::memcpy(a, A{0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05}, sizeof(A));
```

или через `std::copy_n`

```
std::copy_n(std::begin({0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05}), 5, a);
```

или еще через какой-нибудь вариант с `std::initializer_list`.